# How to Support Multiple Screens in Android without the need to Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities

Tags: android

I need to run my application on multiple devices with diffrent specs.
Now I'm trying to get it work on just two: Samsung **Galaxy tab p100** and Galaxy **tab 7.0 plus**
the differnces I'm care about now are dpi,the first device is `240 dpi` the second is `170` and the version the first runs 2.2 he later 3.2
first I put the Images on the `hdpi` folder images on 7.0 plus is smaller and ugly so I copied them to `mdpi` folder works fine but this would **double the size** of my APK.
**Is there any way to make android auto fit Images without the need to copy Images?**

Answer (score 1):

If you want that images look fine in either the device you have to provide the same images for `mdpi` and `hpdi` at differente resolution (see [Alternative drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources)).

However if you put all you images in `mdpi` directory only, Android will *scale* theme for `hpdi` screens. Remember also you have to use `dp` and not `px` for all your dimensions (see [Density independence](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence)).

You can also be interested in how Android *pre-scale* and *auto-scale* resources (see [Additional Density Considerations](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DensityConsiderations)). If you want to force auto-scale, you can add this line in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/>
```

Comment: I did put all stuff in the mdpi folder but the output was bad on the 240 device. I depend on relative layout I rarely set my dimensions explicitly.

Comment: It is normal, if you want to provide only one image resource, its resolution must be acceptable for `hdpi`, also if you put it in `mdpi` folder.

Comment: The system will also scale down your assets - if you put all your highest resolution resources in xhdpi, Android will scale them down on mdpi and hdpi devices - this is generally fine as long as the resource works when scaled down - for example some icons might need to be reworked because they aren't clear when smaller, in which case you provide mdpi and hdpi versions of that asset